# PHP Continue - removed support for variable numeric argument (e.g. continue $num)

Tags: php, loops, continue, php-5.4

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Changelog says that as of 5.4, following change happened:
*Removed the ability to pass in variables (e.g., $num = 2; continue $num;) as the numerical argument.*

Why on earth would they do that?

So, basically, this is now invalid:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $num = 5;
    continue $num;
}
```

Am I understanding this correctly? Why would they do that? I just cannot think of a reason.

Comment: That's not what `continue` does. It skips loop scopes, not iterations within a loop.

Comment: I'm also lacking this feature. I want to skip some number of loops and then process the rest. With the dynamic argument removed from ***continue;*** I cannot do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 5) {
    echo "Outer<br />\n";
    while (1) {
        echo "Middle<br />\n";
        while (1) {
            echo "Inner<br />\n";
            continue 3;
        }
        echo "This never gets output.<br />\n";
    }
    echo "Neither does this.<br />\n";
}
```

here in the above example from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) the continue skips the `echo "This never gets output.<br />\n";` and `echo "Neither does this.<br />\n";` statement and the `continue 3;` denotes the loop number to continue

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $num = 5;
    continue ;
    echo $num;
}
```

the above will skip the printing of `$num`

Comment: couldn't get what you are saying??

Comment: Alright man, thanks for answering, I guess I never really understood this "language construct". 
Also, what I think Mario was saying is that you should've puta reference to your example (i.e. say that you copied it from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

Thanks again from me, gonna mark as accepted.

Comment: Did this answer the question?

Comment: What is the relation of this answer with the question!? I'm having problems being not able to pass a dynamic variable to continue and this answer does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for an alternative function or similar for being able to pass a dynamic variable to ***continue;*** and the accepted answer is nowhere related with the question,

I found a workaround that works instead:

```
$totalLoops = 20;
$skipLoops = 5;
$cnt = 0;
while ($cnt < $totalLoops){
    ++$cnt;  
    if ($cnt <= $skipLoops){continue;}
    echo "Next number is: $cnt<br>";
}
```

Change the **$skipLoops** to how many loops you want to skip and you have an alternative of dynamic continue.